# Why can't I add to props programmatically in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

While using react-native navigator
I am using the DisplayCustomSchema component like this:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
     id: 'DisplayCustomSchema',
     name: 'DisplayCustomSchema',
     org:this.props.org
});
```

In the DisplayCustomSchema component componentDidMount I am calling one ajax post and getting back some data.

```
var DisplayCustomSchema = React.createClass({

             componentDidMount : function(){
                 ajaxpost(data){ // example only
                   this.props.record=data
                  // I am trying to move the response data to props because I am using this data in my saveRecord function but it isn't showing up there.
                 }
              }
              render: function(){
                        <View>
                          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.touchButtonBorder} underlayColor="#ffa456" onPress={saveRecord.bind(this,this.props)}>
                            <Text style={styles.button}>SAVE</Text>
                          </TouchableHighlight>
                        </View>
              }
        })
```

Why isn't data assigned to props?

Comment: `props` are read only.

Comment: but in reactjs it works.but why ti's not works for react native

Answer (score 2):

@zvona is right, `props` are read only.  Not sure how you're getting it to work in reactjs, but you shouldn't be writing to props like that.  Use `state` if you need to do something like that.